# Best way to handle request from different timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an app that can order an item, we have 3 timezone users (UTC+7, UTC+8, UTC+9)
every store is open at 07:00 until 17:00, I need to check if the user request an order but outside working hours, what I have done is sending order time from user app to back-end then I compare the time, but there is a bug, we still can change the time on user app within store's open time and they still can order, what is the best way to handle request from multiple timezone

Note: the back-end server is using Node.js

Answer (score 0):

In frontend app you need to send the shop id and keep that configuration on the backend. You can normalize dates to be set in UTC which should make things easier.

After you send request you know what shop is sending it and in configuration you should get the working hours in UTC. Then you check actual time in UTC and you can decide whether making  order is allowed or not.

It is important to store the dates with timezone offset using correct format (ISO 8601).

Another option is to send the dates using iso 8601 (with timezone offset) and on backend you need to normalize it to UTC and check whether requests are allowed or not.